# Obsolete Swift code won't run on Xcode 12

Tags: swift

So, I recently started a Swift course for beginners on Coursera, but the version of Xcode they use is an old one, meaning that not everything their code do is still applicable. For instance, in the following code, I get these errors:

```
var image = [
    [3,7,10],
    [6,4,2],
    [8,5,2]
]
```

---

```
func raiseLowerValuesOfImage(var image: [[Int]]) {
    for row in 0..<image.count {
        for col in 0..<image[row].count {
            image[row][col]
            if(image[row][col] < 5) {
                image[row][col] = 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
raiseLowerValuesOfImage(image)
```

---

Referring to the line `func raiseLowerValuesOfImage(var image:[[Int]]){` I get the error: **'var' in this position is interpreted as an argument label**

The line `image[row][col] = 5` gives me the error **Cannot assign through subscript: 'image' is a 'let' constant**.

And the `raiseLowerValuesOfImage(image)` returns the error **Missing argument label 'var:' in call**

Can anybody help me to correct these?

Comment: "'var' in this position is interpreted as an argument label" replace `var` with `_`

Comment: "Cannot assign through subscript: 'image' is a 'let' constant" this doesn't even look like Swift, do you know when the course was written? But anyway just delete that line

Comment: "So, I recently started a Swift course for beginners on Coursera, but the version of Xcode they use is an old one" So stop that course. It's useless to you.

Comment: Matt has a good point. A course based on a version of Swift older than Swift 3 is going to cause you more confusion than it’s worth. There was a huge shift from Swift 2 to Swift 3. Since version 3, the changes have been more incremental. I would NOT invest time in learning Swift 1 or 2 now.

Comment: And given how fast things change, I’d suggest finding courses based on Swift 5.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Swift hasn't supported declaring function parameters as vars for a long time.

My guess is that this program is supposed to modify that values in the array that is passed to it.

In recent versions of Swift, you tell the compiler you want to be able to modify a parameter passed to you and return the modified values by marking the parameter as `inout`

Rewriting the code you posted to use inout:

```
var image = [
    [3,7,10],
    [6,4,2],
    [8,5,2]
]

func raiseLowerValuesOfImage(_ image: inout [[Int]]) {
    for row in 0..<image.count {
        for col in 0..<image[row].count {
//          image[row][col] // This line doesn't make sense. delete it.
            if(image[row][col] < 5) {
                image[row][col] = 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To call a function with an `inout` parameter, you pass the parameter marked with a `&` symbol, which tells the compiler to pass the parameter "by reference". You could run the function on your array with code like this:

```
raiseLowerValuesOfImage(&image)
print(image)
```

That outputs

> [[5, 7, 10], [6, 5, 5], [8, 5, 5]]

Which is what I would expect from that function.

### Edit:

I did some more digging, and the `var` qualifier on parameters does not allow you to return the changed values to the caller. The function, as written, modifies a local copy of the `image` array that’s passed to it, and then when the function returns, those changes are discarded. I don’t see the point of that code.

Comment: I think that's exactly why they got rid of the `var` param. It makes it look like there's something special about how the param is passed to the function,but there isn't. The effect is purely internal. So now, so is the `var` declaration. — Also: "In recent versions of Swift, you tell the compiler you want to be able to modify a parameter passed to you and return the modified values by marking the parameter as inout" No, inout is not recent. It was in Swift 1.